# can we send data from pdf and web page to server in adobe livecycle

Tags: adobe, livecycle

My assignment is text box, dropdown in pdf and radio button, check box in web page then will it be possible to send both data's to server in Adobe livecycle?

Comment: Please explain detail.

Comment: In an editable pdf (which has text box and drop downs )  and inside a web page (radio buttons and checkbox).  Is it possible for the pdf to capture the value of the fields displayed in the browser as well as pdf? 
We want all these field values(text box, drop downs, radio buttons and checkbox )  to be sent to the server once the user clicks the submit button that is placed inside the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send PDF form data on web server. You will be need to use adobe live cycle designer.

Step1: Create HTTP Submit button on your PDF form.
step2: Enter URL of your web server inside HTTP button.

Answer (score 0):

You can also send the data to a server via a SOAP based web service using the SOAP object. You can find details here:

[Adobe SOAP Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_SOAPWS%2FSOAP_and_Web_Services.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from your webpage to the PDF, you should take a look at [Form Bridge](https://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/help/mobile-forms/form-bridge.html)

By binding JavaScript events to your webpage fields, you could update hidden form fields every time the webpage fields are updated. With the form now transporting your webpage data, you can submit it back to your server using either SOAP or REST.

SOAP will allow you to wrap your data submission in an envelope, but when dealing with a PDF if the state of the document matters (signatures, etc.), posting the full document or even just the data to a REST endpoint can be achieved very easily using a [Submit](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/livecycle/lc_understanding_submit_tip.pdf) button on the form.